# Можно ли писать приложение Android только на С++

Tags: java, android, c++, android-sdk

Я собираюсь научиться разрабатывать приложения под Android. Я знаю, что приложения под Android разрабатываются на языке Java, но также можно и на С++. Так вот, можно ли не учить Java и использовать только С++, чтобы писать приложения под Android или обязательно нужно знать Java?

Comment: обязательно нужно знать Java/ На чистом С++ написать приложение под Android не получится никак, потому что сам фреймворк Android написан на Java

Comment: а зачем тогда нужен С++? можно ли тогда на чистом java писать?

Comment: Не только можно, но и нужно. С++ используется для выполнения отдельных операций, критичных по скорости, например, какие то объемные расчеты. Обычному приложению не требуется код  на С++, как правило

Comment: чтобы начать писать под Android на каком уровне нужно знать java и С++?

Comment: С++ нужно знать на нулевом уровне (не знать о нем ничего). Java - на достаточном для того, чтобы писать код, который будет делать то, что вы желаете от этого кода. Так же критично необходимо знание самого фреймворка Android (его классы, архитектура приложения и тп)

Comment: Можно начать знакомство с платформой с этого [очевидного сайта](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

Comment: я вот на С++ знаю основы, но на java ноль. За сколько можно научиться писать на java/android простые приложения? достаточно простые

Comment: Все индивидуально и зависит от многих факторов: способности писать код в принципе, прошлого опыта, опыта ООП в частности .. Программисту с опытом в других языках ООП для написания достаточно простого приложения потребуется .. ну пара недель на все про все - ознакомится с синтаксисом, конструкциями и поштудировать офф.документацию, без опыта программирования от пары месяцев до бесконечности - сроки весьма условны. Мне потребовалось где то полгода чтобы начало получаться то, что мне бы хотелось получить, а самое простое - недели.

Comment: на самом деле можно. Посмотрите в сторону кокоса/мармелада (игровые движки). Если C# - то Юнити.

Comment: Можно писать на C++ с использованием библиотеки Qt.

Comment: если речь идет не о играх, то с кокосом, мармеладом, юнити и особенно qt получится не приложение, а слезы и боль

Comment: @pavlofff, можете раскрыть Вашу мысль подробнее? На Qt пишут приложения как под iOS, так и под Android, что с ними не так?

Comment: @ixSci Если речь идет о стандартных приложениях (не играх) то не так всё - начиная от не нативного вида виджетов и большого размера apk и заканчивая далеко не полной совместимостью с SDK Android и  кучей необъяснимых багов, ответы на которые спросить, как правило, не у кого. Хотя я интересовался этим года 3 назад, но сомневаюсь, что с тех пор что то сильно изменилось. Достаточно погуглить на эту тему и станет ясно, что без крайней необходимости (кросс-платформенная разработка на Qt) с этим лучше не связываться.

Comment: @pavlofff, ясно, спасибо, погуглю ещё. Мне просто предстоит писать кроссплатформенное приложение, и я пока не решил, что делать. Думал использовать Qt, т.к. в целом, на десктопе, это хорошее кроссплатформенное решение, а вот в мобильном сегменте я сам с ним не работал ещё.

Comment: @ixSci Кроме того дополнительно в систему требуется установка эмулятора Qt (3 года назад требовалась), что явно не плюс, с некоторыми компонентами системы\устройства могут быть большие проблемы, в частности с полями ввода, камерой, отриcовкой при смене состояний и пр. С другой стороны 2GIS под Android написан на Qt и вполне работает (и кажется это единственное успешное приложение под Android на Qt :) ). Вообще, энтузиасты как то пишут, с матами, бубнами, но результат есть.

Comment: @ixSci Все же для кросс-платформенной разработки лучший, безусловно Xamarin, и по совместимости с поддерживаемыми платформами и в плане IDE, по нему и сообщество есть, чтоб спросить . Кроме того с недавних пор он бесплатный. Хотя и в Xamarin предостаточно багов. всяких костылей и не решенных проблем, но меньше чем в других кросс-платформенных решениях.

Comment: Если ты будешь писать небольшие программы, игры и т.д., то можно использовать C++. Например, использовать Qt или игровой движок Cocos2d-x. Java знать не обязательно. Если всё грамотно написать, то никакой боли не будет и приложение будет работать нормально.

Comment: А такой вопрос, как понять какое приложение не будет поддерживать какую-нибудь версию Android и какой-нибудь смартон, как узнать какие характеристики нужны Android смартфону для Android приложения?

Comment: https://developer.android.com Здесь всё есть. Посмотри и все найдешь

Comment: Если Вы хотите научится писать под андройд, пишите под андройд штатными средствами. Если Вы хотите изучить C++ учите язык без андройда. Вам шашешчки или ехать?

Answer (score 2):

Странно, что не вспомнили проект [crystax](https://www.crystax.net/ru)

У разработчков проекта есть примеры простеньких прложений на С++. Насколько я знаю, в их планы входило делать нативные библиотеки для разработки UI и прочих тповых задач.