# Недостатки использования Qt для Android

Tags: android, qt, playmarket

Никогда не писал приложения для Android. Однако, беглое чтение сопутствующей литературы приводит к мысли, что использование средств разработки, отличных от Java - неэффективно.

**Вопрос:** Каким образом собираются и публикуются общедоступные приложения под Android, разработанные с помощью Qt и NDK, что нужно учитывать? Под каждую процессорную архитектуру собирать отдельно?

Comment: В QtCreator можно делать. Под каждую архитектуру отдельно, естественно. Дело вообще гиблое, совместимость по API слабая, виджеты не нативные, сообщество практически отсутствует .. Не так давно [обсуждали в комментариях](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604662/Можно-ли-писать-приложение-android-только-на-С#comment822819_604662), можете почитать. Не думаю, что тут найдется практикующий разработку на Qt под Android, чтобы дать полноценный ответ, тут Google то мало что путнего сказать может.

Comment: [toster](https://toster.ru/q/61124)

Comment: Статейка староватая, и "заангажированная" в пользу Qt )) Хотя пару абзацев таки подтверждают мои опасения.

Comment: Прошло уже полтора года, а Qt все бурнее развивается в этой области. И мне как разработчику С++ удобнее для собственных нужд накидать приложение на Qt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Qt - это всё-таки C++. Разрабатывать на нём существенно сложнее, чем на Java. То есть дольше и с большим количеством ошибок.
2. Инструментарий разработки для C++ однозначно хуже такового для Java в силу, опять-таки, особенностей языка.
3. Java - родная платформа для Android. Отсюда потенциальные проблемы с совместимостью у Qt.

Если вы опытный С++ разработчик, то вам, наверное, будет удобнее использовать Qt. В противном случае - не вижу преимуществ перед Java (касательно разработки под андроид).

Если вы планируете разрабатывать для ряда мобильных платформ, то qt хороший выбор. Если сугубо для андроида, то я на стороне Java.

Comment: Категорически не согласен с первыми двумя пунктами. А в остальном - гуд. Все ответы всех ответивших пометил как "полезные", даже бы разделил награду поровну. Если бы мог. Этот ответ помечу - как решение. Потому как размышления о недостатках Qt для Android еще раз напомнили - да "ряд мобильных устройств, в том числе и не-android" очень важны.

Answer (score 7):

Если зырить в корень, то конечно же проблема Qt не в его возможностях или наоборот невозможностях. Qt умеет делать на Android'е примерно то же самое что и Java на Android'е.

Основной недостаток это отсутствие коммьюнити. Далеко ходить не будем и возьмем количество репозиториев на [github](https://github.com):

- с поддержкой Java Android - 276 тысяч
- с поддержкой Qt Android - 340 штук

Разница почти в 3 порядка (почти в тысячу раз). Это означает, что у вас будет в тысячу раз меньше документации, в тысячу раз меньше примеров, в тысячу раз меньше библиотек/визардов/контролов, в тысячу раз меньше экспертов, в тысячу раз меньше людей с которыми вы сможете обсудить свои проблемы ну и т.д.

В реале наверное будет не тысяча раз - пусть даже сто, но я бы поостерегся в самом начале своего пути Android девелопера так опрометчиво не полагаться на силу Java community.

Переходите на сторону силы :)

Answer (score 3):

если вы хорошо знаете java и не знаете qt/qml, то пишите на java, если не знаете ни то ни то, поспрашивайте ещё тех, кто имеет опыт обоих языков.
Я сторонник Qt.

Comment: Неплохо знаю Qt, а яву не знаю. Опыт разработки только для десктопа.

Comment: вы сейчас примерно такой же, как и я. Опыт с Qt. Полтора месяца назад начал изучать QML, за месяц наловчился, понравилось.

Comment: попробуйте сделать вот такие примеры, простейшие

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7xUhmqameI

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1aWyJ_YXxU

Comment: Увы, QML меня совсем не интересует. Судя по http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/platform-notes-android.html так же имеет место генерация нативного кода.

Comment: Пока нашел вот такое решение - https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Comment: Год назад посматривал в сторону Haxe (http://haxe.ru/about-haxe). Просто печально, такой интересный подход, но с начала разработки, а это 2005 год, вроде, "а воз и ныне там". Хотя, генерация C++ и Java кода - манит.

Answer (score 3):

Пишу на Java и считаю что самый лучший способ. Qt на мой субьективный взгляд однозначно нет а вот на счет C++ и NDK можно поспорить. Смотрел видeо по разбору NDK и там проводились тесты на скорость работы Java и C кода. Второй компилируется быстрее, в некоторых случаях намного быстрее. Поэтому есть смысл использовать NDK в тяжелых проектах. Также нашел инетерсную статью на хабре https://habrahabr.ru/post/272423/.