# Реклама на Qt. выходит ошибка

Tags: android, qt

Решил добавить рекламу в приложение на андроид созданное на Qt, но добавить рекламу тут составляет огромную проблему. По этой инструкции (https://habrahabr.ru/post/261425/), я старался внедрить рекламу, но компиляция останавливается и появляется такое сообщение:

> C:\Users\PC\Documents\build-Tests-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_8_0-Debug\android-build\AndroidManifest.xml:51:13 Error:
>       Missing 'name' key attribute on element meta-data at AndroidManifest.xml:51:13
>   :processDebugManifest
>   C:\Users\PC\Documents\build-Tests-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_8_0-Debug\android-build\AndroidManifest.xml:85:5 Warning:
>       Element uses-permission#android.permission.INTERNET at AndroidManifest.xml:85:5 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:76:9
>   C:\Users\PC\Documents\build-Tests-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_8_0-Debug\android-build\AndroidManifest.xml:86:5 Warning:
>       Element uses-permission#android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE at AndroidManifest.xml:86:5 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:77:5
>   C:\Users\PC\Documents\build-Tests-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_8_0-Debug\android-build\AndroidManifest.xml:0:0 Error:
>       Validation failed, exiting
>   :processDebugManifest FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
>     Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 1 mins 18.122 secs
>   Building the android package failed!
>     -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
>   18:47:27: Le processus "C:\Qt_folder\x\Qt\5.8\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" s'est terminé avec le code 14.
>   Erreur lors de la compilation/déploiement du projet Tests (kit : Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.8.0))
>   When executing step "Build Android APK"

Comment: помогите вот [заодно человеку](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/611018/177345), если есть опыт

Comment: @pavlofff Пока опыта нету, не публиковал приложения, хочу начать.